# Pointer to a Class Type

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, pointers

Essentially I'm trying to work around the problem of not being able to store derived types as a derived type in a (value) array of a base type. I have multiple classes that store one to three ints but have to have very different sets of functions. I'd use an array of pointers but the entire array is traversed forwards, then backwards constantly, mostly linearly, so keeping it all together in memory is preferable. I could create multiple arrays, one for each type and then an array of pointers to each of those, but that would get pretty clumsy fast and really wouldn't be the same as each element packed neatly between the one preceding it and the one proceeding it in order of access at runtime.

So what I'm thinking is that I make a POD struct with three ints and a pointer and fill an array with those, then use that pointer to access polymorphic functions. It would end up something along these lines: (forgive the poor coding here, I'm just trying to convey the concept)

```
class A { 
    int aa( &foo f ) { return 1; }   
    int dd() { return 9; } 
};
class B : A {
    int aa( &foo f ) { return f.b; } 
};
class C : A {
    int aa( &foo f ) { return cc() + f.c - f.a; }
    int cc() { return 4; }
};
class D : B {
    int dd() { return 7; } 
};
struct foo{ int a, b, c; A* ptr; };

const A AA = A(); const B BB = B(); const C CC = C(); const D DD = D();
foo[100] foos;

init() {
    foo[0] = foo{ 1, 2, 3, &BB };
    // etc fill foos with various foo elements
}
bar(){
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i ){
        print foos[i].ptr.aa( &foos[i] );
        print foos[i].ptr.dd();
    }
}
main(){ 
     init(); 
     while(true)
         bar(); 
}
```

I'm just wondering if this is the best way to go about what I want to achieve or if there's a better solution? Ideally I'd just point to a class rather than an instance of a class but I don't think I can really do that... *ideally* I'd store them in an array as multiple derived types but for obvious reasons that's not going to fly.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a discriminated union, like Boost.Variant?

Comment: Besides never having come across them? I'm not sure. How would I make one polymorphic while retaining the same type without a bunch of clunky switch statements in each function?

Comment: OK, just checking whether you knew about them and had ruled them out. They should do what you need, with visitation instead of a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are virtual functions.

In the bellow example :

```
  class A
  {

       virtual void foo(){printf("A is called");};
  }
  class B : public A
  {
         void foo(){printf("B is called");};
  }

  ...
  A* ptr = new B();
  ptr->foo();
```

Will produce "B is called" .

If you don't want to use virtual functions (to save memory for example), you can use dynamic cast , but this will lead to significant performance loss.

Please not that you need to have at least 1 virtual function to perform dynamic cast.

In the example bellow :

```
    class A {...}
    class B : public A {...}
    class C : public A {...}

    A* ptr1 = new C();
    B* ptr2 = dynamic_cast<B*>(ptr1);
    C* ptr3 = dynamic_cast<C*>(ptr1);
```

ptr2 will be null, and ptr3 will have a value.
So you can make the following (very wrong) construct :

```
     if (ptr2)
     {
        ptr2->bb();
     } else if (ptr3)
     {
        ptr3->cc();
     }
```

Finally, you can get rid of dynamic casting by having your own typing mechanism and then just C cast to the correct class.

Comment: What's the impact virtual functions have on memory? If I have only one instance of each class initialised and several pointers that point to each of those classes would that have the same impact as if I had several instances of each class (provided the functions were accessed at the same rate)?

Comment: I don't really want to cast anything explicitly or have to figure out the type manually if I can avoid it because I want to move through the array as fast as possible...

Comment: Then use virtual functions or functors arrays inside the object and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You need polymorphism. In your example all the classes have standard methods. You need to make them virtual, so the polymorphism can be applied.

```
class A { 
    virtual int aa( foo& f )const { return 1; }   
    virtual int dd()const { return 9; } 
};
class B : A {
    virtual int aa( foo& f )const { return f.b; } 
};
class C : A {
    virtual int aa( foo& f )const { return cc() + f.c - f.a; }
    int cc()const { return 4; }// this doesn't need to be virtual because is not in the base class A
};
class D : B {
    virtual int dd()const { return 7; } 
};
```

Here is some information on this topic: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/. There is some information on how to use pointers as well.
I would suggest to look at smart pointers: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/?kw=shared_ptr
Another topic you should look at is constness: search for "constness c++" (cannot post more then 2 links)

```
struct foo{ int a, b, c;const A* ptr; }; // const A* instead of A*
```

Comment: Thanks for the links! 
Does that declare a const pointer to A or a pointer to a const A?

Comment: Here you can get some info: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/general/article.php/c6967/Constant-Pointers-and-Pointers-to-Constants.htm
And it is a pointer to const A.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I'm trying to work around the problem of not being able to store derived types as a derived type in a (value) array of a base type.

You *can* store derived types, as values, in an array - you just can't store them as instances of the base type.

A `union` of your concrete leaf types is almost what you want, but there's no way to figure out which member of the union is live, or to use polymorphic dispatch.

A *discriminated* union is one which tells you which member is live, but doesn't directly help with the dispatch.

[Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant/) is a specific discriminated union which provides a clean mechanism for polymorphic dispatch - not using `virtual`, but using a visitor with overloads for each concrete stored type. In this case, you don't even need the stored types to be related to a common abstract base - they can be entirely unrelated. Look for `apply_visitor` in the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic) for details.